# TypeScript access and change global variables

Tags: typescript, variables, global

I want to change a global variable from another file in TypeScript using modules and require.js setup.

app.ts :

```
import { change } from "./change"
export let a : number = 1;
change(); // a should be 2 by now
```

change.ts :

```
import { a } from "./app.ts"
export function change () {
  a = 2; // error
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `a` becomes read-only after importing it from a module. You cannot change local variables in module B from module A.